# Angular js $http.get call with multiple ID's(urls)

Tags: angularjs, api, http

I have an api ('rest/latest/testruns/16543558') the id is test run ids . I want to make a call with different ids in oneshot and store the value in object for ng-repeat in my view.

```
$http
  .get('rest/latest/testruns/' + testplanid)
  .success(function (response) {
    $scope.testruns = response;
  })
  .error(function (data, status) {

  });
```

Comment: Where you are calling the `$http` in your controller?

Comment: Just to clear up your goal here, you have an array of `id`s and for each you want to make a call to your REST endpoint and have all values returned at once so you can store the results in some value? If that is the case, you should look up `Promise.all` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 1):

can use `$q.all` to send multiple http requests at once.

```
 var ids = ['16543558', '16543559', '165435510']
 var fullArr = [];

 for (id in ids) {
    fullArr.push($http.get("rest/latest/testruns/" + id))
 }

 $q.all(fullArr).then(function(arrayOfResults) {
    //return the response of all equest
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) like below to achieve the similar behavior

```
var ids=[1,2,3,4,5], promises;

promises = ids.map(function(v){
return $http
  .get('rest/latest/testruns/' + v)
});

$q.all(promises).then(function(responses){
  // responses[0]  => id 1
  // responses[1]  => id 2
  // responses[2]  => id 3
  // responses[3]  => id 4
  // responses[4]  => id 5
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $q.all to achieve the multiple promise calls.

HTML code :

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="PromiseCtrl">
      {{result}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller function :

```
function PromiseCtrl($scope, $q, $timeout) {
    // Our promise function with its delay as argument
    var getPromise = function(delay) {
        // Creates a Deferred object
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function() {
            // Resolve the promise at the end of the delay if said delay was > 0
            if(delay > 0) {
                deferred.resolve("Success");
            } else {
                deferred.reject("Fail");
            }
        }, delay);

        // The promise of the deferred task
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    // Init
    $scope.result = "Waiting";

    /*
     * Combines multiple promises into a single promise
     * that will be resolved when all of the input promises are resolved
     */
    $q.all([
            getPromise(1000),
            getPromise(2000),
            getPromise(3000) // <--- Try something less than 0
        ]).then(function(value) {
        // Success callback where value is an array containing the success values
        $scope.result = value;       
    }, function(reason) {
        // Error callback where reason is the value of the first rejected promise
        $scope.result = reason;
    });
}
```

Please find the plnkr : https://jsfiddle.net/samirshah1187/Lpach13a/